# jquery table cell click action

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have jQuery code as below:

```
$(document).on("click", "#chkSelectAll", function (e) {
     window.alert("Test");
 });
```

When I do a click on Select All check box the alert is displayed, but in firebug returns an error:

> TypeError: e.push is not a function

Strange thing is that when I click each item separately using:

```
$(document).on("click", "#tblCTCProducts tbody tr label input", function (e) {
    window.alert("Test");
});
```

firebug is not returning any errors.

EDIT I:
I am using [DataTables Table plug-in for jQuery](http://datatables.net/)

EDIT II
Including partial view which I am using:

```
@model IEnumerable<EUVCCD.ViewModels.VM_EUVCCD_Product>

<div id="divProductsTableHolder" class="col-md-12 container CheckBoxesPartial" style="white-space: nowrap;">
    <table id="tblProducts" class="table centered table-small table-bordered" style="width: 100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <input id="txtSearchProduct" placeholder="Search Product" class="col-md-12"/>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline col-md-12">
                        <input id="chkSelectAllProducts" type="checkbox" value="-1" name="All" />All</label>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label id="lblProduct_@item.ID" class="checkbox-inline col-md-12">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="@item.ID" name="@item.ProductName" class="ProductsCheckbox"/>@item.ProductID - @item.ProductName</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Do you think the issue may be in head of the table where Select All check box resides?

Comment: @KonstantinDinev Why? What should I use instead?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools I still don't like the FF dev tools, but it's a little better than FireBug. Firebug is a third party tool and is not functioning very well for years now.

Comment: In second code you should have error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )(…)`

Comment: @KonstantinDinev Thanks for quick response. What would you recommend for Chrome?

Comment: Chrome dev tool works fine ;)

Comment: Chrome dev tools is good.

Comment: @jcubic I wrongly copied second code. Now it's ok.

Comment: @KonstantinDinev I used Chrome dev tool and it returned:"Uncaught TypeError: e.push is not a function"

Comment: Can you create or update this fiddle where is your problem? I have no errors in FF or Chrome dev-tools: https://jsfiddle.net/pleinx/p1p7Ldu7/

Comment: @ironcurtain apparently what you've posted in the question is not all of your code.

Comment: So is there anything else attached to the table? The code above should not throw any errors.

Comment: @KonstantinDinev I am using http://datatables.net/ for the table

Comment: Check where the error is coming from. It could be from datatables.

Comment: @KonstantinDinev I've noticed that when I move Select All check box to tbody, error does not appear. Unfortunately I would prefer to have this check box in the thead.

Comment: Your code works fine, see http://jsfiddle.net/eLsvqndn/